# List files in system paths that are not tracked by package manager system

Tags: apt

I need to list all files that came to system manually and are not accounted by apt package manager. How can I do that?

Comment: This is problem about looking for files to be copied to reproduce current working system on another similar (not the same) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple way to check if file is tracked by package manager `dpkg -S`.

```sh
$ fdfind . /usr -tf -x dpkg -S >/dev/null
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/ttyd
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/share/dispsetup.sh
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/libsysev.so
```

or the same

```sh
$ find /usr -type f | xargs dpkg -S >/dev/null
```

Comment: As you can see i ask here dpkg not apt. So files installed with dpkg -i should not be shown to stderr

Comment: I see. I think the problem is that `apt` doesn't maintain a list of files installed, it uses `dpkg` to do that, so how can we distinguish between files installed via `apt` and installed not with `apt` but `dpkg`? Some files might be created via post-installation-scripts, so even installed via `apt` or `dpkg` they will show up using the suggested commands. We can also manually install via `apt`, the question is not really clear in this point. I think what OP wants is more complicated or even impossible at all. This let me think your comment under the question hits the point better.